# Модификатор "i" не работает в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Опять проблема с регулярными выражениями в PHP. Собственно код:

```
<?
$sw="аромат";
$pattern="#.*$sw.*#i";
$v="АрОмАт";
preg_match_all($pattern, $v, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Результат:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

Другими словами модификатор "i" не работает. У кого-нибудь такое бывало?

Comment: У меня такое бывало и не раз, насколько я понял, проблема в кодировке, а не в модификаторе, обходил всегда с помощью других регулярок.

Comment: Я тоже так подумал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
$pattern = '/.*' . preg_quote($sw) . '.*/iu';
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: Ключевой момент - модификатор `u`

> **u (PCRE_UTF8)** Этот модификатор включает дополнительную
> функциональность PCRE, которая не
> совместима с Perl: шаблоны
> обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки.
> Модификатор u доступен в PHP 4.1.0 и
> выше для Unix-платформ, и в PHP 4.2.3
> и выше для Windows платформ.
> Валидность UTF-8 в шаблоне проверяется
> начиная с PHP 4.3.5.